# How to plugin TestNG in eclipse Juno?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to plugin "TestNG" in eclipse Juno?I was failed to add from eclipse market place and also from the Help-> install new software, please suggest any alternate way.

When I am trying from the Eclipse Market place, it's throwing error like "The following solutions are not available: TestNG for Eclipse"

and When trying the same from "install new software " by giving http://beust.com/eclipse in Work with field, it's saying "There are no categorized items".

Looking for the solution.
Please help.

Comment: **Juno** is literally the oldest version that would work. Eclipse has had 3, nearly 4, releases since. Try it again with the current release, **Mars.2**, and with the option to group items into Categories unchecked.

Comment: Try installing the plugin directly from the site: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/testng-eclipse?mpc=true&mpc_state=